# IPF.Imap can not be listed by graph api /users/{user_id}/mailFolders/{folder_id}/childFolders

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

As stated in the title, I am unable to list folders with `FolderClass="IPF.Imap"` using graph api `/users/{user_id}/mailFolders/{folder_id}/childFolders`.

However, the `IPF.Imap` folders are listable by graph api `/users/{user_id}/mailFolders/{folder_id}` (eg. given folder id) and also listable by ews api `SyncFolderHierarchy`.

Is this a limit by graph api? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is that an IMAP4 folder imported into an Exchange mailbox? Or an Exchange mailbox accessed through IMAP4 in Outlook?

Comment: Hi @DmitryStreblechenko, it's an IMAP4 folder imported into an Exchange mailbox.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Graph shows `IPF.Imap` folders. Try to either remove the `PR_CONTAINER_CLASS` MAPI property or set its value to `"IPF.Note"`. If it is a one-time deal, you can edit/delete that property in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author, select the folder in Outlook, click IMAPIFolder button on the OutlookSpy ribbon, select the `PR_CONTAINER_CLASS` property), otherwise you should be able to change that property programmatically using Outlook Object Model (`MAPIFolder.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty`) or Extended MAPI on the client side.